# clickhouse - Clickhouse imported data is forcibly killed by the system

Tags: database, clickhouse

When I import a 120g text file to the `Clickhouse`, there are 400 million data in it. After importing more than 100 million data, I will be killed.

The import statement is as follows:
`clickhouse-client --user default --password xxxxx --port 9000 -hbd4 --database="dbs" --input_format_allow_errors_ratio=0.1 --query="insert into ... FORMAT CSV" < /1.csv`

The error is as follows:
`2021.04.29 10:20:23.135790 [ 19694 ] {} <Fatal> Application: Child process was terminated by signal 9 (KILL). If it is not done by 'forcestop' command or manually, the possible cause is OOM Killer (see 'dmesg' and look at the '/var/log/kern.log' for the details).`

Is the imported file too large, bursting the memory? Should I subdivide the file again?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at system logs - they should have some clues:

1. as suggested in the error message - run *dmesg* and see if there's mention of OOM Killer [ kernel self-protection mechanism triggering on out-of-memory events ]. if that's the case - you're out of memory or you've granted too much memory to clickhouse.
2. see what clickhouse own logs tell. path to the log file is defined in clickhouse-server/config.xml, under yandex/logger/log - it's likely /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log + /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log